# How to call different XSL resources using the same XSLT Transformer

Tags: spring-integration

I have to call 2 different XSL depending on some basis set in the input XML .

I don't want to write 2 separate transformer for this task. The current Code has been written like this

```
 <int:router input-channel="inputchannel"
       default-output-channel="outputChannel" expression="headers.get('someValue')">

      <int:mapping value="x" channel="xChannel" />
      <int:mapping value="y" channel="yChannel" />

 </int:router>

 <int-xml:xslt-transformer inputChannel="xChannel" output-channel= "output"
                xsl-resource="xRelated.xsl" />
 <int-xml:xslt-transformer inputChannel="yChannel" output-channel="output"
                xsl-resource="yRelated.xsl" />
```

However , this seems to be a dirty solution as this is just a sample . I will be having 14 different type of XSLs. Does anyone have an idea,how can I re factor this.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Integration `XsltPayloadTransformer` relies on `TransformerFactory` abstraction which preduces `Templates` based on `Source` from underlying XSTL.

So, looks like there is no choice to have just only one component who can handle several XSLT at once.

It would be great, if know other XSLT engine which can provide desired solution, but it hasn't to be based on standard `TransformerFactory`.